# Number of independent coefficients of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, projective-space

Consider $R_d=k[X_0,\ldots, X_n]_d$, the homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables. The dimension of $R$ viewed as $k$-vector space is $\binom{n+d}{d}$ so a general polynomial in $R$ has $\binom{n+d}{d}$ coefficients.

Now, let $d$ be divisible by $2$ and $3$ and $f\in R_{d/2}, g\in R_{d/3}$. Consider the polynomial $h = a_1\,  f^2 +a_2\, g^3\in R_d$. Is it possible to compute the number of independent coefficients of $h$ for generic $a_i \in k$?

It has to be $\leq\binom{n+d}{d}$ but I do not figure out what the exact value is.

Comment: Note that the homogeneous polynomials in $n+1$ variables of degree $k$ are in correspondance with the general polynomials in $n$ variables of degree $\le k$, e.g. by the expedient of setting $X_0 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, I do not see how this shall simplify the situation.

Comment: Help me understand what "independent coefficients of $h$" means in this context.  A narrow interpretation is that $f,g$ are fixed and $a_1,a_2$ are allowed to vary, but this seems too narrow to pose much difficulty in discerning "the number of independent coefficients".

Comment: @hardmath:  My original problem is to count the complex moduli of a elliptically fibered Calami-Yau which is given in Weierstraß form. The speciality is that the sections $f$ and $g$ appearing in the Weierstraß form are not of general form but in the form I cited in my question. The number of complex moduli equals the number of coefficients of $f$ and $g$ modulo symmetries. To compute the actual number of coefficients I compute the rank of the above Jacobi matrix. I hope this makes the situation clearer to you.

Comment: Is it fair to say we can vary not only $a_1,a_2$ but $f,g$ as well?  I think we can then count coefficients that vary independently if we exclude the exceptional case $f^2=g^3$.